# How to make my discord bot send an emoji if a message has a emoji in it?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make my discord bot send an emoji whenever the message has an emoji in it.
With my code it does even throw back and error, and does not send a message to the guild.

```
import discord
import os

TOKEN = os.environ['something'] #for obvious reasons

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
   emojis = [':grin:', ":joy:", ":rofl:", ":scream:",":+1:",":-1:"]

     for i in message.content:
       if i in emojis :
         await message.channel.send(i)


client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: When you do `for i in message.content:`, what kind of thing do you expect `message.content` to be? What do you get as each `i` value when you iterate over that? Do you understand why you would never find such a value `in emojis`? What if you iterate over `emojis` instead - what will the individual elements be? If you had those, do you see how you could use it to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `for i in message.content:` you iterate through all message content characters, e. g. `h`, `e`, `l`, `l`, `o`.

To check if message contains one of substrings you should write something like this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    emojis = [':grin:', ":joy:", ":rofl:", ":scream:",":+1:",":-1:"]
    for emoji in emojis:
        if emoji in message.content:
            await message.channel.send(emoji)
```

Comment: But the result is same. The bot does not send a message back to server... Btw thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Pura Marpu I think that emojis are unicode characters in discord messages. You should write `` instead of `:joy` and so on.

Comment: @Pura Marpu Then could you accept my answer, please? (if it was helpful)

Comment: Why not!! I will.